# UserRepository no existe

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy utilizando laravel para servir api´s al momento de consumir una para autenticacion me lanza el siguiente error:

```
exception: "ReflectionException"
file: "laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php"
line: 811
message: "Class App\Repositories\Auth\UserRepository does not exist"
```

Sin embargo ya tengo mi UserRepository en el siguiente namespace

```
namespace App\Repositories\Auth;
```

Por cierto ya intente con el comando composer dump-autoload

Mi composer es el siguiente:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/passport": "~4.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "~2.0",
    "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.11.0",
    "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "5.5.x-dev",
    "infyomlabs/swagger-generator": "dev-master",
    "appointer/swaggervel": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
    "intervention/imagecache": "^2.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
    "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
}, ....
```

Actualizo y agrego la estructura de directorios.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade la estructura de tus directorios para saber donde has colocado tu clase `UserRepository`

Comment: Añade el composer.json para que podamos ver entre otras el `psr-4`

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: Que namespace tiene UserRepository ? El folder Repositories tiene otro folder adentro llamado Auth ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probando un par de cosas me di cuenta que el problema real era otro, 
estaba haciendo uso de una funcion llamada `count`dentro de una clase BaseRepository.

```
 public function count()
{
    $this->applyCriteria();
    $this->applyScope();

    $result = $this->model->count();

    $this->resetModel();
    $this->resetScope();

    return $result;
}
```

Detecte el error haciendo uso del comando de rutas de laravel. `php artisan route:list`

obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
In Container.php line 811:
Class App\Repositories\Auth\UserRepository does not exist
In MyBaseRepository.php line 13:

 Declaration of App\Repositories\Auth\MyBaseRepository::count($where = Array, 
 $columns = '*') should be compatible with 
  Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository::count(array $where = Array, $columns = 
  '*')
```

Pues resulta que la version 7.1.30 de PHP para esa funcion dentro de laravel espera parametros.

```
public function count($where = Array(), $columns = '*')
{
    $this->applyCriteria();
    $this->applyScope();

    $result = $this->model->count();

    $this->resetModel();
    $this->resetScope();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta +1